# Trying to find the difference in days between 2 dates

Tags: python, pandas

I have a date column in my dataframe and I am trying to create a new column ('delta_days') that has the difference (in days) between the current row and the previous row.

```
# Find amount of days difference between dates
for i in df:
    new_date = date(df.iloc[i,'date'])
    old_date = date(df.iloc[i-1,'date']) if i > 0 else date(df.iloc[0, 'date'])
    df.iloc[i,'delta_days'] = new_date - old_date
```

I am using an iloc because I want to directly reference the 'date' column while i repersents the current row.

I am getting this error:

> ValueError: Location based indexing can only have [integer, integer
> slice (START point is INCLUDED, END point is EXCLUDED), listlike of
> integers, boolean array] types

can someone please help

Comment: You cannot use `date` as an index entry. Select the column first, then use the index.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`pandas.DataFrame.shift`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html) method to achieve what you need.

Something more or less like this:

```
df['prev_date'] = df['date'].shift(1)
df['delta_days'] = df['date'] - df['prev_date']
```

Comment: Thank you it seems to work on newer versions of python but not in Google Co lab that is using 3.6.  When I try to run in colabs i get the error: TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'str'

Comment: can you share your sample data?